# What is the current Node.js driver for Cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm starting to use [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) Database, and I'm trying to find a decent `node.js` driver for that. But everything is very confusing, let me explain what I had found.

First driver I found is [helenus](https://github.com/simplereach/helenus), and I'd search for this one because that was the one that [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032193394X) mention at the beginning (still reading). The book is not old; the first edition was released on `December 29, 2013`. So should not be that outdated.

Then, on the [helenus](https://github.com/simplereach/helenus) repository I found this message:

> This driver uses the old Thrift protocol if you are using Cassandra 1.2 or higher and you are using CQL, please consider using [node-cassandra-cql](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql). While I will continue to fix bugs with this driver, feature development is frozen as many new features coming out will not be supported by Thrift.

So, logically I went to the [node-cassandra-cql](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql) repository but another message appears:

> This is not the driver you are looking for
>
> node-cassandra-cql has graduated from community driver to being the foundation of the official Datastax Node.js Driver for Apache Cassandra.

At this point I was a little confused, everything appears to be changing too quick. I did a little more research, and I ended up with this three repositories:

1. [The Datastax driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver) (the one that `jorgebay` recommends on his repo)
2. [The node Cassandra client from Rackspace](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client)
3. [Apollo Cassandra](https://github.com/3logic/apollo-cassandra) (based on Datastax driver)

So, at this point I am a little confused, and I wanted to ask to the `node.js` community, what modules should I use for developing on `Cassandra`? Why?

For what I'd see none of the above looks like production ready to me, but I am new to Cassandra so maybe (and for sure) I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The book is not old; the first edition was released on December 29,
> 2013. So should not be that outdated.

2013 is a loonggggg time in Cassandra time.

Use the DataStax driver, it's [full featured](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/2.2/nodejs-driver/whatsNew.html) like the other DataStax drivers which means it has automatic failover, topology awareness, etc. etc.

If you want an ORM, Apollo may be a good choice in the near term until the DataStax driver gets an ORM. It's built on the datastax driver so you get the key features and performance.

The rackspace one's [last commit](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client/commits/master) was Aug 26, 2014 which should help you make a decision there...

#### Some history:

As Jorge mentioned, his community driver was absorbed by DataStax, transformed into the datastax driver and contributed back into opensource.

It's a lively community as you can see by the mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/nodejs-driver-user

Follow progress and report bugs/ideas on Jira!
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=11&projectKey=NODEJS&view=detail

Answer (score 0):

[Cassandra-co](https://github.com/kunalgolani/cassandra-co) is another ORM inspired by Apollo Cassandra, actively maintained, and used at scale in production.

Disclaimer: I'm the author